Rolling resistance uphill
In this interactive model of cycling power and speed, the rolling resistance depends on the grade:
$$F_{rolling} = 9.8076 * cos(arctan(grade))*W*C_{rr}$$ where $W$ is system mass, $C_{rr}$ is the coefficient of rolling resistance, $grade$ is rise/run.
Why does it make sense to assume that the rolling resistance depends on the grade in the way modeled? Does the tire somehow push "into" the grade? Or is the model incorrect? Elsewhere I checked the $cos(...)$ factor is not included.
(The model clearly distinguishes $F_{rolling}$ from $F_{gravity}$ which is the force required to lift the system up the grade.)

The rolling resistance depends on the normal force on the plane, wich is $W*g*cos(\alpha)$ with $\alpha$ the angle of the inclined plane.

Thank you! This is mindboggling. This means that at a grade of 0, the rolling resistance is maximal but when you go uphill or downhill it decreases! The extreme case of 90 degree downhill makes sense: the wheel can just freely roll along without being deformed. For uphill, I don't have a similar intuition because the wheel has to "hold" the bike with some form of friction.

If you try to go uphill in snow or ice you feel the difference!
